# HTA Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 8070000c

Tags: javascript, hta

So, I have an HTA that I am having problems with when trying to create or open a text file to log.

It works fine on Windows 7 64bit on IE 11.
When I try it on Windows 10 64bit, I get the following error:

**Could not complete the operation due to error 8070000c.**

The line the error is on is below:

```
   var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   var f = fso.OpenTextFile('log\\log.txt',2,true); // <-- Error is on this line!
```

It seems to be like a permission error. I've searched for about 2 hours and can't figure out what is the cause / solution.

Again, it works fine on Windows 7, but not on Windows 10.

Same HTA is below:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
<head>
<HTA:Application Border='yes' ContextMenu='no' Caption='no' Scroll='auto' Singleinstance='yes' Windowstate='maximize' application='yes'>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9' />
<title>KIOSK</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jQuery/jquery-3.1.0.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // Log File.
    function writeToLog(dStamp, msg) {
        var loc = window.location.pathname;
        var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('\\'));
        dir = dir + '\\log\\log.txt';
        // alert(dir);
        //Create FSO Object
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        //First, make sure the LOG exists
        if (!fso.fileExists("log\\log.txt")) {
            //alert("FILE DONT EXIST!");
            try {
                var f = fso.OpenTextFile(dir,2,true);
                f.close();
            } catch(e) {
                alert("The following error was found: " + e);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            dtTime = new Date();
            //This function was added because if the log file gets over a certain size, I want to rename it and make a new one
            var f = fso.OpenTextFile(dir,1,false);
            var fSize = f.Size;
            if (fSize > 1000000) { //If file is larger than 1Mb, rename and create new.
                fileExists = true;
                fileNumber = 0;
                newFileName = f + "-" + (dtTime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dtTime.getDate() + "-" + dtTime.getFullYear();
                while (fileExists) {
                    if (fso.fileExists(newFileName)) {
                        fileNumber++;
                        newFileName = f + "-" + (dtTime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dtTime.getDate() + "-" + dtTime.getFullYear() + "_" + fileNumber;
                        fileExists = true;
                    } else {
                        fileExists = false;
                    }
                }

                fso.MoveFile(f, newFileName);

                //And create my new one
                f = fso.OpenTextFile(dir,2,true);
                f.close();
            }
        }

        //Now, open the log file
        var f = fso.OpenTextFile(dir, 8);

        //Now, write to the log file
        //First, check to see if we want a date stamp before this message
        if (dStamp == true) {
            dtTime = new Date();
            nLine = dtTime + "\t" + msg;
        } else {
            nLine = "\t" + msg;
        }

        f.WriteLine(nLine);

        //Finally, close the log file... until next time...
        f.close();
    }
</script>
<body ondragstart='return false' style='text-align:center;'>
    <input type="button" onclick="writeToLog(true,'Test Log HTA');" value="Test Log" />
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Likely UAC, run `mshta.exe "your.hta"` with elevated privileges.

Comment: Your time might be better spent on moving away from HTA. Microsoft has signaled that it is a "legacy" technology. See [this connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/785055/hta-application-tag-does-not-work-in-ie10) for the official word.

Comment: I understand that HTA's are legacy technology. Unfortunately, that is what I am working with for now.

Comment: Looks like it may have been a path issue. I updated it to get the path of the application, and now it's working.

Comment: Expected that response tbh, @MikeMcCaughan these types of comments are never really very helpful. Sometimes you have a choice sometimes you don't.

Comment: @Lankymart Never? I've made this kind of comment about other "legacy" technologies and gotten good feedback along the lines of "Oh, they don't support that?"  and "Thanks for the link, maybe it will convince the boss". I concur that sometimes you don't have a choice. Only a couple years ago I had to support IE7 on a project despite it being EOL. Once I brought up that security patches would no longer be issued for the version, the client relented. So, sometimes you have a choice, and need to know you have a choice.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ok, fair point... *"never"* is a bit ott.

Comment: I thought I fixed it, I was incorrect. Still having this issue. :(

Comment: Did you try elevated privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had some incorrect values being passed to OpenTextFile and that was basically causing all of my issues.
The corrected and "working" script is below if anyone ever needs it. :)

```
// Log File.
function writeToLog(dStamp, msg) {
    var loc = window.location.pathname;
    var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('\\'));
    dir = dir + '\\log\\log.txt';
    // alert(dir);
    //Create FSO Object
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    //First, make sure the LOG exists
    if (!fso.fileExists(dir)) {
        //alert("FILE DONT EXIST!");
        try {
            var f = fso.CreateTextFile(dir, true);
            f.close();
        } catch(e) {
            alert("The following error was found: " + e);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        dtTime = new Date();
        //This function was added because if the log file gets over a certain size, I want to rename it and make a new one
        var f = fso.OpenTextFile(dir,1,true,0);
        var fSize = f.Size;
        if (fSize > 1000000) { //If file is larger than 1Mb, rename and create new.
            fileExists = true;
            fileNumber = 0;
            newFileName = f + "-" + (dtTime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dtTime.getDate() + "-" + dtTime.getFullYear();
            while (fileExists) {
                if (fso.fileExists(newFileName)) {
                    fileNumber++;
                    newFileName = f + "-" + (dtTime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dtTime.getDate() + "-" + dtTime.getFullYear() + "_" + fileNumber;
                    fileExists = true;
                } else {
                    fileExists = false;
                }
            }

            fso.MoveFile(f, newFileName);

            //And create my new one
            f = fso.CreateTextFile(dir, true);
            f.close();
        }
    }

    //Now, open the log file
    var f = fso.OpenTextFile(dir,8,true,0);

    //Now, write to the log file
    //First, check to see if we want a date stamp before this message
    if (dStamp == true) {
        dtTime = new Date();
        nLine = dtTime + "\t" + msg;
    } else {
        nLine = "\t" + msg;
    }

    f.WriteLine(nLine);

    //Finally, close the log file... until next time...
    f.close();
}
```